# Sort github repo by number of issue open

Tags: github

Suppose I search for any keyword in github , then is it possible to sort github repo by number of issues open?

Comment: This is too broad as asked. Do you mean via the web interface? Via the API? Are you searching for _repositories_ by keyword or something else? Please explain _exactly_ what you're trying to do. And what does it have to do with [tag:github-pages]? See [ask].

Comment: Hi Chris , sorry for late reply , I mean to say for example I search for keyword "operating system" in github.com ( webpage ) , then github will display multiple repo or open source operating systems ( or something related to that ) , Now say I want to sort by number of issue open , like OS with highest number of open issues on 1st rank of search , is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so, but feel free to take a look at the [advanced search page](https://github.com/search/advanced?q=operating+system&type=Repositories)

Comment: @pankajkushwaha - Did you figure it out?

Comment: No , I don't think there is any such option , all you can do that fetch number of open issue by web scraping and then sort it.